# WebdriverIO - Test fails with error Openfin

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I have been trying to setup automation testing for our openfin application using the below repo as base

https://github.com/openfin/webinar-automated-integration-tests

I am using Openfin (Chrome version 61.0.3163.100) and Chromedriver 2.40.565498

When I run "npm test", the openfin application opens up. But the tests don't run. After waiting for sometime, it throws the below error in console.

```
ERROR: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

chrome

I tried using other versions of chromedriver like 2.33, 2.34, 2.37, 2.38, 2.39, 2.41. Using these versions even the application doesn't appear. So, I guess the chromedriver version I am using is correct. I have also tried adding the below arguments to chromeOptions

```
--remote-debugging-port=9222,--no-sandbox,--headless,--disable-gpu
```

They didn't solve my issue. Not sure what is causing the issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.40*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- Presumably you are using *chrome=61.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome 60-62**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v60.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v80.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 80.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using WebdriverIO in the place of selenium. Also as mentioned in my question itself I tried running chromedriver 2.33 but that resulted in a different error and the application did not pop up at all

Answer (score 0):

You must pair your OpenFin Runtime with the correct version of ChromeDriver. The `second` number in your OpenFin runtime version corresponds directly to the Chrome version.

i.e., for latest stable - `30.110.74.8` - you would use ChromeDriver for Chrome `110`

This is a new package OpenFin provides which automates this required pairing -https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openfin/automation-cli